# How to make exuberant-ctags parse "using" style typedefs?

Tags: c++, c++11, ctags, exuberant-ctags

How can I make ctags parse `using` type aliases, like the one below?

```
using FooPtr = std::shared_ptr<Foo>;
```

It only picks up ones declared with `typedef`.

Comment: May be, it's time to update the C++ support: [How to Add Support for a New Language to Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html). ;-)

Comment: exuberant ctags is outdated for years! See the answer from Mastake. There is a new derived version which is under development. It also has no trouble with lambda and other "new" stuff. BTW: C++11 is out for 7 years now? You had a long break I believe :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Universal-ctags(https://ctags.io) forked from Exuberant-ctags handles 'using' in c++ source file:

```
[jet@localhost]/tmp% cat /tmp/foo.cpp 
using FooPtr = std::shared_ptr<Foo>;
[jet@localhost]/tmp% u-ctags -o - /tmp/foo.cpp
FooPtr  /tmp/foo.cpp    /^using FooPtr = std::shared_ptr<Foo>;$/;"  t   typeref:typename:std::shared_ptr<Foo>   file:
```